# Two Spring applications with same controller web layer but different UI styles

Tags: css, spring, spring-mvc

I have an existing Spring MVC 4 application that uses JSP (no templates). I am  tasked to develop a very similar application with exact functionality but with a different UI style (with different font styles, background colors).

How can I achieve this by reusing all the controller/web layer java code but apply different styles to the jsp?

My application is currently organized as a set of eclipse projects listed below.

- JavaProject1 (Domain objects)
- JavaProject2 (Dao's and Services)
- WebProject (controller/jsp)
- EarProject (wrapper around the webproject)

Now, for the new application, I do not want to create a new WebProject and copy over all the controller/jsps. Instead, just apply a new style. Any thoughts on how effectively this can be achieved.

Comment: Do you need to execute one or another, am I right?

Comment: I need both applications running alongside. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [Spring MVC Theme resolver options](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver), where you can change css dynamically per session, request (interceptor) or have defaults.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using maven overlays.

> An overlay of a WAR file, is simply a Maven project that uses another
>   project's WAR output as a dependency, rather than a project's JAR.
>   When the overlay project is built, the underlying project's WAR file
>   is exploded and files in the overlay project added to it. If an
>   overlay project has a file with the same path and name as a file in
>   the underlying WAR it will replace it.

Here you have some more info about it: http://www.ensor.cc/2011/06/mavens-war-overlay-what-are-war.html

And a step-by-step guide: https://github.com/iipc/openwayback/wiki/Creating-a-WAR-overlay

Comment: Thanks Luke. Unfortunately, we are still using ant and red tape approvals are required for using Maven. I will remember about overlays when we eventually migrate to maven.